# How does an inflationary universe solve the Flatness Problem, Horizon Problem and Monopole Problem?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the evidence for Inflation of the early universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/what-is-the-evidence-for-inflation-of-the-early-universe)

I am reading some public science books on inflationary universe, e.g. [The Inflationary Universe](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CCEQFjAAOAo&url=http://www.amazon.com/Inflationary-Universe-Alan-Guth/dp/0201328402&ei=-iCqUJz8DK6jiAfg6oDYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFaGrv71HsWgfYTcLmvk8-RAGxkrw&sig2=yDBnfDzP6Mm_hz8m5Sqknw) by A. Guth.

Both in this book and the Wiki page mention briefly how this theory of inflation can possibly solve Flatness Problem, Horizon Problem and Monopole Problem. But their explanations are too sketchy for me.

Can somebody give a detailed explanation? But I do not want something too technical. I am doing this for a presentation in my general education class. The professor is a prominent physicist so I need some more details to satisfy him, but most of the audience are just *average* college students.

How does an inflationary universe solve the Flatness Problem, Horizon Problem and Monopole Problem?

Comment: This is largely a duplicate question. See also [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/8560/2451) Phys.SE answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a comment rather than an answer, but it got too long to put in a comment.

**Flatness problem:**

[On Flatness problem, Inflation etc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/on-flatness-problem-inflation-etc)

[Why does inflation (the inflaton field) push Omega down closer to zero (flatten the universe)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23410/why-does-inflation-the-inflaton-field-push-omega-down-closer-to-zero-flatten)

[How does inflation drive Ω close to 1?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/how-does-inflation-drive-close-to-1)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem

**Monopoles:**

[How does Inflation solve the Magnetic Monopole problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12484/how-does-inflation-solve-the-magnetic-monopole-problem)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopole_problem#Magnetic-monopole_problem

**Horizon problem:**

I couldn't find a match question on this site but see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem.

Each of the three subjects, the flatness problem, the horizon problem and the monopole problem is a long answer in it's own right. I'd suggest you have a look at the links above and ask a new quaestion about any specific issues you don't understand.